# Mass update printer drivers on Windows server

Tags: windows, drivers, upgrade

We have a bestiary of Kyocera printers - from FS-1028 to Taskalfa 4002 (17 different models in total). Novadays most printer manufacturers provide universal, omni-device drivers. So does Kyocera: it provides the package like `KX710330_UPD_signed`, which contains drivers for most of their printers and MFUs.

On Windows server I can see 17 different drivers. It's almost OK. But these drivers are of different versions.

Now I want to massively upgrade all Kyocera's drivers using the abovementioned omni-package. And I can't! I must manually "re-install" driver for every model in order to replace it with newer version. And it is very "boring", or annoying - to choose model from the narrow section of non-expandable window etc.

I have several servers with such menagerie of drivers, and repeat the same steps hundreds of times in row will drive me crazy.

Is there any way to upgrade all installed printer drivers from given location? One driver a time, but automatically, one by one? It's OK. Full-auto? It's also OK. :-)

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42563942/powershell-script-to-change-printer-drivers-on-several-printers

Comment: Thank you, @marsh-wiggle , but it is not the thing I asking for.

Comment: For example, I've Kyo FS-1028 with driver version 5.x and Kyo KM-2560 with driver 6.x. Both these drivers must be replaced with version 7.x.

More, the printers 002, 013 and 017 are FS-1028, and printer 029 is KM-2560 - no any correlations between printer's name and its driver. We have about 75 printers, some of one model, some of another etc...  And I need just update the drivers on the print server.